# Using JavaScript arrays similar to SQL: How can any generic JavaScript array of hashes object be filtered similar to SQL where condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I could have generated the following code. But the condition being plain string is open to errors in future.

Is there a better (elegant) way in JavaScript or ReactJS to make a code similar to SQL where conditions?

(Please note that, the solution I search is not only for a specific array object.)

```
function filter_by_where_condition (p_cur_item) {
  return eval (l_conditions_as_string);
}
/*
    Usage Example:
    // l_conditions_as_string paramter holds the where condition, should be modified dynamically
*/
l_arrayofhashes = [ 
    { foo: 1, bar: 2, someotherelement: 1}, 
    { foo: 3, bar: 4, someotherelement: 1}, 
    { foo: 5, bar: 6, someotherelement: 13}, 
    { foo: 5, bar: 16, someotherelement: 1} 
];
l_conditions_as_string = "p_cur_item.bar >= 3 && p_cur_item.bar <= 7 && p_cur_item.foo == 3"
l_arrayofhashes.filter(filter_by_where_condition);
// returns [ { foo: 3, bar: 4, someotherelement: 1} ]
```

For reference the SQL counter part is obviously like that:

```
create database if not exists stackoverflow;
use stackoverflow;
drop table if exists arrayofhashes_as_table;
create table arrayofhashes_as_table
(
    foo integer,
    bar integer,
    someotherelement integer
);
insert into arrayofhashes_as_table(foo, bar, someotherelement) values
(1, 2, 1),
(3, 4, 1),
(5, 6, 13),
(5, 16, 1);
commit;
select *
    from arrayofhashes_as_table p_cur_item
    where p_cur_item.bar >= 3 
        and p_cur_item.bar <= 7 
        and p_cur_item.foo = 3;
-- Returns
-- foo  bar someotherelement
-- 3    4   1
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function filter_by_where_condition (arr,condition_string) {
 for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  var p_cur_item = arr[i]
  if(!eval(condition_string)){
   arr.splice(i,1)
   i--
  }
 }
 return arr
}

l_arrayofhashes = [ 
    { foo: 1, bar: 2, someotherelement: 1}, 
    { foo: 3, bar: 4, someotherelement: 1}, 
    { foo: 5, bar: 6, someotherelement: 13}, 
    { foo: 5, bar: 16, someotherelement: 1} 
];

l_conditions_as_string = "p_cur_item.bar >= 3 && p_cur_item.bar <= 7 && p_cur_item.foo == 3"

console.log(filter_by_where_condition(l_arrayofhashes, l_conditions_as_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object with special structure for searching, if you need to search for more than one item. This proposal uses an object, with this structure for filtering:

```
{ 
    bar: {
        min: 3,
        max: 7
    },
    foo: 3,
    /* model: function (s) { return s.match(/s/); } // just search for a single letter */
}
```

The algorithm looks for every property in `search` and if *all* comparisons are `true`, then the element is added to the result set.

```js
function filter(array, search) {
    return array.filter(function (a) {
        return Object.keys(search).every(function (k) {
            return (
                a[k] === search[k] ||
                typeof search[k] === 'object' && (
                    ('min' in search[k]) && ('max' in search[k]) && search[k].min <= a[k] && a[k] <= search[k].max ||
                    ('min' in search[k]) !== ('max' in search[k]) && (search[k].min <= a[k] || a[k] <= search[k].max)
                ) ||
                typeof search[k] === 'function' && search[k](a[k])
            );
        });
    });
}

var array = [{ foo: 1, bar: 2, someotherelement: 1 }, { foo: 3, bar: 4, someotherelement: 1 }, { foo: 5, bar: 6, someotherelement: 13 }, { foo: 5, bar: 16, someotherelement: 1 }],
    condition = { bar: { min: 3, max: 7 }, foo: 3 };

console.log(filter(array, condition));
```

For a smaller implementation of a `where` clause, you could use a callback for filtering, like

```js
var array = [{ foo: 1, bar: 2, someotherelement: 1 }, { foo: 3, bar: 4, someotherelement: 1 }, { foo: 5, bar: 6, someotherelement: 13 }, { foo: 5, bar: 16, someotherelement: 1 }],
    condition = function (o) { 
        return o.bar >= 3 && o.bar <= 7 && o.foo === 3;
    };

console.log(array.filter(condition));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
l_arrayofhashes = [ 
    { foo: 1, bar: 2, someotherelement: 1}, 
    { foo: 3, bar: 4, someotherelement: 1}, 
    { foo: 5, bar: 6, someotherelement: 13}, 
    { foo: 5, bar: 16, someotherelement: 1} 
];
l_conditions_as_string = "p_cur_item.bar >= 3 && p_cur_item.bar <= 7 && p_cur_item.foo == 3"
var res = l_arrayofhashes.filter(function(currentValue, index, arr) {
    return currentValue.bar >= 3 && currentValue.bar <= 7 && currentValue.foo == 3;
}, l_arrayofhashes);
for(var e in res){
    console.log('foo: ' + res[e].foo + '; bar:'+res[e].bar + '; oth: '+ res[e].someotherelement);
}
```

**currentValue, index, arr** are the parameters passed to ***array.filter*** function and the array itself goes as a second parameter being **this** into the filter function.

The result is an array containing only those elements passing (return true) filter conditions.